# Excel VBA: Calling a function from one sheet that searches data on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets of data.

On other sheets I need to search on one of the data sheets.

In the function I am using to start the search I have a parameter called firstcell which tells the the search function where to start.

What happens is the search function thinks firstcell is on the sheet where the calling function is and not the data sheet.

How do I pass the correct sheet to the search function?

```
Function GetValue(firstcell as string, searchterms) As Variant

''firstcell is the name of a named cell on the data sheet
''searchterms is a list of values that gets passed

. . . .

    GetValue = MySearch(Range(firstcell), searchterms)

'' this is where firstcell becomes the address of the named cell but on the sheet where the function is
. . . .


End Function    'GetValue
```

Thanks

Comment: If you pass `firstcell` as a Range then you can use that range directly in your function

Comment: Here is how I am declaring MySearch: `Function MySearch(FirstCell As Range, ResultColumn As Integer, ParamArray SearchTerms() As Variant) As Variant` I think I am passing firstcell as a range? If I am not, then how do I? Thanks

Comment: As long as you're calling it using a range and not a string then that should work. How did you modify the content of the function?  Can you update your post to show your new code (add it at the end  - please don't replace the original code)